# NSArray sort Criss cross

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I have an Array

> @["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]

and i want to sort it criss cross like the following

> @["A","G","B","F","C","E","D"]

so that the last item slips every 2 times to the front.

Comment: Have tried to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you haven't tried anything. If it's because you haven't found any algorithm, or can't figure one in your mind, this code could be helpful:

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    BOOL tail= NO; // To know if you should remove from array's tail or head.
    NSMutableArray* array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G"] ]; // The unsorted array.
    // This will contain sorted objects:  
    NSMutableArray* sorted=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity: array.count];
    // The algorithm will end when array will be empty:  
    while(array.count)
    {
        NSUInteger index= tail? array.count-1:0; // I decide the index of the object
                                                 // to remove.
        // The removed object will be added to the sorted array, so that it will
        // contain the object on head, then on tail, then again on head, and so on...
        id object= array[index];
        [sorted addObject: object];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex: index];
        tail= !tail;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",sorted);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as:

Break the array into halves.

Sort both of them.

Merge both to them again to form your result. Here you need to iterate alternative, i,e step+=2

**EDIT: The running code follows**

```
NSArray *array=@[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G"];
NSArray *halfLeft=[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count/2+1)];
NSMutableArray *halfRight=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
[halfRight removeObjectsInArray:halfLeft];
NSMutableArray *finalAray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:halfLeft];
for (NSInteger i=0, index=1; i<halfRight.count; i++, index+=2) {
    [finalAray insertObject:halfRight[halfRight.count-1-i] atIndex:index];
}
NSLog(@"%@",finalAray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple loop, adding objects to the output array as you go;

```c
NSArray *input = @[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H"];
NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Quickly add all except possibly the middle one, makes the loop simple
for(int i=0; i<input.count/2; i++)
{
    [output addObject:input[i]];
    [output addObject:input[input.count-i-1]];
}

// If there is an odd number of items, just add the last one separately
if(input.count%2) 
    [output addObject:input[input.count/2]];
```